# vue vue-chartjs chart.js set different point styles for each dataset

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I have a multiline line chart, works nicely, I have a graph title, axis titles, different colors for each line, legend.

What I cannot get working is having a different point style, marker, for each data set.  They all use a circle.

I have tried setting the pointStyle but it isn't working:

```
{
  label: "Total Jobs",
  backgroundColor: "#f82279",
  borderColor: "#f82200",
  pointStyle: "triangle",
  data: [
    93, 94, 105, 105, 92, 94, 101, 82, 16, 25, 23, 19, 10, 13, 14, 12, 11,
    11, 14, 13, 27, 16, 21,
  ],
```

What am I missing here please?

thanks

Ken

Comment: There's no problem in the fragment you listed, see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vfk74Lts/), it makes triangles.

Comment: @kikon thank you, yes it does seem to work.  I added a second data set to your fiddle and changed the color and point to a circle and it indeed does work.  I will now re-visit my code and see where I may have erred.  Thanks again for your effort.